# How can I get featured image url for woocommerce Shop page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is the code by which I am trying to get featured image url to set as BG. It's working fine for page.php. But in Woocommerce Shop (post-type-archive-product) page it is showing one of product featured image instead of page featured image.

Any solution??

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

    <header style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0']; ?>')" class="inner-page-header">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="page_header">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `wc_get_page_id()` to get the page ID and use that to get the image source. This should work.

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ), 'full' );?>

    <header style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0']; ?>')" class="inner-page-header">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="page_header">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Here is [the documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_page_id.html)